# SVG files in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I wanted to create an icon in css, with an svg in between, just the way I saw in duolingo, I have given the screenshot (because you’ll have to login to see). When I saw the source, I saw that there is an svg file with all the icons as a pack, but individually they were set as icons in circles. I suppose that they have used the viewBox property in svg. I just wanted to know I guessed right, and if it is a sensible way, or should I use PNG files?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, but I guess they were using the [CSS Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) technique in conjunction with SVG images instead of using PNGs. This is great for when you have vector graphics and would like to support high-dpi devices ("Retina" and "4k" screens).

Putting them into the same file just reduces the network load and improves loading time. Using SVG also improves network bandwidth usages for these kind of graphics *and* yields the best fidelity.

So unless you need to target older browsers, using SVGs is a great idea, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Just visited Duolingo. They use different techniques, as far as I recognize it. Indeed they cut out icons from some kind of sprite to display these. However, they also use RaphaëlJS to import SVGs which is nice, because it is very easy to manipulate the SVG afterwards.

You can use them to adapt the size of your graphics depending on the resolution of the viewer. However, be aware that older browsers don't support SVG very well (Raphaël has a great backwards compatibility here, but the browser limits still apply).

SVG are surely consume smaller amounts of storage and bandwidth. So it is up to you, if you want to use these or not. If you need to manipulate the graphics it's the way to go IMHO. However, if you need to support old browsers go with png.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on if you are going to support IE8 or not. It's about 3% global usage. Unfortunately for the sector I work for, its more like 10% so I need to support it.

Inlining SVG, as you've described, is a great way to use SVG sprites. SVG elements are available to be styled by CSS so if you name your SVG elements appropriately, you could do something like:

```
.food-level-2 #icon-food.level-marker-2,
.food-level-2 #icon-food.level-marker-1 {
    fill: orange;
}

.food-level-3 #icon-food.level-marker-3,
.food-level-3 #icon-food.level-marker-2,
.food-level-3 #icon-food.level-marker-1 {
    fill: orange;
}
```

Which is awesome! User levels up, you change the class from .food-level-2 to .food-level-3, put a nice transition in there, and all is happy. But this is totally not supported by IE8, and hard to do a fall back for.

Background images, as with traditional css sprites, are very easy to make a fallback for.

```
.food-level-2{
    background-image: (../img/food-level-2.png);
    background-image: (../img/food-level-2.svg);
}
```

If the browser doesn't understand svg, it falls back to the png. Generating extra PNGs is easy if you're using something like font-squirrel or grunt/gulp. Make it a SASS mixin to write the .pngs first, .svgs second.

All is, less happy, but ok. You spend more time in Illustrator making all the possible variations. This looks like the route Duolingo choose with 1-1 png fallbacks. You still get crispy vector graphics where supported, and generally reduced load times.